# Long lines in blockquote breaks layout in 10k mod tools

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, design, blockquote

One of the answer to this question ["Unrecognized configuration section connectionStrings."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785437/unrecognized-configuration-section-connectionstrings/3315312) shows up in the 10k mod tools, and it breaks the layout when I expand the content: the post body takes up the whole width of the page, instead of 725px.

The breakage is caused by the long lines in blockquote. On closer investigation, it seems that removing `width: auto` for `table.flagged-posts .post-text` fixed the issue (I am not sure whether the property is used for anything else, though).

Sample screenshot:

[image]