# Flag Review queue doesn't wrap post text in expanded format

Tags: bug, review, flags, code-formatting, markdown

10k users have access to another set of queues, where they can see some of the flags, close votes, comment wars etc.

Posts are by default shown in a collapsed format, with no formatting enabled (no block quotes, links, code formatting etc). To see the formatting, we need to expand the post.

Today I came across an [obviously wrong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15117746/1069068), which in the collapsed form looks like this:

[image]

However, when I expand it, there's no wrapping of text at all. It just becomes one huge line of `Console.Readline();`, as shown here:

[image]

This line continues for a while, and affects the formatting of the rest of the page. The usernames of the other flagged posts get pushed to the extreme right, and the sidebar of the review page gets pushed to the bottom of the page, right above the SE network links. I accidentally closed the tab, so I can't get a screenshot of that.

The answer formats properly on the normal question page, but it doesn't wrap the text on the review page. Could this be fixed?

Comment: I'm not sure it's completely related, but I'll throw it in the ring for completeness - I had something similar on a question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165773/question-overflows-outside-presumed-question-area

Comment: @JonClements Yeah I've seen that too, but I don't think its the same problem here.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158917/long-lines-in-blockquote-breaks-layout-in-10k-mod-tools