# Large quoted blocks overflow in the 10k tools

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, design

Browsing the "Excessively long" flagged posts in the 10k tools (with Chrome) I've noticed that large quoted texts seem to overflow and invade the right sidebar.

(Might be related to [Layout slightly broken for large strings in questions on Google Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132485/169503))

[image: Picture]

Comment: Looks like a [duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158917/169503)? Voting to close ...

Comment: Nice find, I took the courtesy to add your screenshot in there hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: Thank you for doing so :)

Comment: Sure thing, anything to help make things better. ;-)